# Angularjs bootstrap datepicker for month and year only

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working on a bootstrap datepicker which will show only month and year. To some extent I have succeeded. I feel there is an issue with the import files sequence that the datepicker input box size is not correct. I have attached the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWAZ2i8GGFYvFCcjMM2h?p=preview). Need to click on Report Details on the left panel to check the actual output I am getting. 
I need help with Index.html import file re-sequencing. Somebody please check it.

I am just adding a small code snippet. For the whole code please check the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWAZ2i8GGFYvFCcjMM2h?p=preview)

```
       <div class="form-group">
  <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div>
   <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
   <input data-format="MM-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1"></input>
   <span class="add-on">
   <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
   </span>
   </div>
   </div>

  </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input class = "form-control" data-format="MM-yyyy" id="input1" name="input1"></input>
```

add .form-control to input tag and remove type="text" seemed to have worked.